# Setup Multiple website Magento 2.1 on Shared hosting with no SSH access and NO Virtual Host setup

Tags: magento-2.1, multi-website

I want to setup two different websites on the same Magento 2.1 Installation.
The two websites will have different products and different domain (not on the same host). Right now I have only registered one domain and I'm trying to configure multiwebsite to work on mydomain.com and shop.mydomain.com (or mydomain.com/shop). I have tried different tutorial but nothing seems to work.

I'm on a Shared Hosting with no SSH and I'm unable to follow the Magento DevDocs all the way through because I can't create a Virtual host or run code with ssh.

I have also tried this two tutorial with no luck:
https://www.forgeonline.co.nz/magento-multistore-website-shopfront/
https://www.fmeextensions.com/blog/how-to-create-configure-multiple-store-views-in-magento-2/

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have figured out a solution with my hosting provider by using aliases instead of virtual host and is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a solution with my shared hosting provider by using aliases instead of virtual host.
My provider add to apache configuration:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.mywebsite\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE="mycode1"
SetEnvIf Host www\.mywebsite\.it MAGE_RUN_TYPE="website"
SetEnvIf Host www\.mywebsite2\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE="mycode2"
SetEnvIf Host www\.mywebsite2\.it MAGE_RUN_TYPE="website"
```

And add aliases pointing to the same directory of my main website. Not perfect but it works